# How to use css styling in a php echo output

Tags: php, html, css

I got this piece of code that shows output from a database in a table. The last column shows the output on a button and can be clicked to go further.
I am looking for a way to style the button with css, but its not doing what i need at all.

```
<?php
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
        ?>

        <tr align="center">
            <td><?php echo $row['klasse']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['orde']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['onderorde']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['familie']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['onderfamilie']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['soort']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['ondersoort']; ?></td>

            <?php
            $output = $row['ned_naam'];
            echo "<td> <a href='info.php?value=". $output ."'><button>" . $output . "</button></a> </td>"; 
        echo "</tr>";
    }
    ?>
```

I tried:

```
<button class=\'btn\'>" . $output . "</button></a> </td>";
```

but that doesn't seem to work at all. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: What do you want to do? its not clear from the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no reason to use escape character `\` on single quote  since you wrapped your `echo` in double quotes

```
echo "<button class='btn'>" . $output . "</button>";
```

Comment: thanks, tried that too before and it wouldn't show the button at all. Same happened again, but then i realized that 'btn' was a reserved class for bootstrap (which i use also). So i changed it to <button class='bttn'> and it worked like a charm. Thanks for waking me up :).